# What effort did the Luftwaffe make to prevent Operation Torch landings in North Africa 1942?

Tags: world-war-two, war, nazi-germany

Did the Germans know about the Operation Torch landings in late 1942 and if so what steps were taken in particular by the Luftwaffe to intervene?

Comment: Some minimal effort would have given you that information easily.